# create a java-properties file beneath the .war file

Tags: java, servlets, properties, path

When I export my Dynamic Web Project, I want that the .properties file is in the same folder as the .war file. 
Oh and I need both the Windows and the linux variants of the solution if there is a difference. (I already read [here](http://crunchify.com/java-properties-file-how-to-read-config-properties-values-in-java/) how to create and read from a .properties)
I want the user to be able to edit the .properties file

Answer (score 1):

I recommend setting your project up using mavens war plugin.  You can add an option to put resources were you want in the war file.  See the link below.

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html

Comment: I already use maven to deal with importing libraries. Do I have to download anything or can I just apply the changes to my pom.xml?

Comment: Just apply the changes in the link above to your pom after your dependencies section.  Might take a bit of tinkering around to figure out how to get maven to put the file exactly were you want it though.  I don't know the exact lines you would need off the top of my head.